# Mongoose, Function Cannot Be Performed on Undefined, From Query Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use today's date as the field on which to 
search - at this juncture, without having to worry about integrating the *moment.js* library. There will be only one record with today's date in the "table".

```
app.dashboardreport
    .findOne()
    .$where(function() {
        return this.createdOn.toJSON().slice(0, 10) == Date.now().toJOSN().slice(0, 10);
    })
    .exec(function(err, foundDashboardReport) {
```

The `$where` function is throwing an error.

> MongoError: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined
>       at _funcs1 (_funcs1:2:26) near 'createdOn.toJSON().slice(0, 10) == Date.n'  (line 2)

It appears that "this" may not be defined; however, I know there is a record which meets those criteria.

Am I structuring the query incorrectly? If so, what needs to change in the function so that I can filter on that condition?

Comment: Does every single document in your collection have a `createdOn` field?

Comment: Also: you'll get a second error once this one is fixed. Typo at `toJOSN`

Comment: @Prinzhorn would the absence of a field from a document - i.e. if the data was differently structured - cause this error?

Comment: Yes, this would error if createdOn is not present in every document.

Comment: You do something like this if the field `CreatedOn` is not present in every document: (this.createdOn|| new Date('31 Dec 9999')).toJSON()

Comment: @Jaco that's the answer; not sure if you want to submit an answer to the question or not. It's not a hugely generic OP, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, here, is a lack of understanding of the way in which data is structured in document-based storage. Each document must contain the `createdOn` field - if it is absent, then you will receive this error. `this` is defined; `createdOn` is not.

If you have data that is not uniform, you need to evaluate the presence of the field. So, it might look like this:

```
app.dashboardreport
    .findOne()
    .$where(function() {
        /* The check for the field createdOn ensures that the compared document 
           does indeed contain the field */
        return this.createdOn && this.createdOn.toDateString() == new Date().toDateString();
    })
```

Note the addition of the `this.createdOn` evaluation in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error a `CreatedOn` is not present in every document. You could so something like this to get around this:

```
(this.createdOn|| new Date('31 Dec 9999')).toJSON()
```